# nhibernate +criteria. How to return result without one referenced entity

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have criteria:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
                .SetFetchMode("Entity1", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("Entity2", FetchMode.Select)
                .SetMaxResults(max)
                .SetFirstResult(min)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Available", true))
                .CreateAlias("Entity3", "b")//, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("b.Name", variable))
                .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
```

When I execute this query, all fields from Entity3 are returned to. 
How can I execute it and have in result only Entity objects with referenced Entity1 and Entity2 without Entity3?

Comment: There is a strong probability that this is undoable. Why do you not want references to Entity3 objects?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help.

```
IList criteria2 = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(class1), "cl1")
.CreateAlias("subclass1.subclass2", "s2")
.CreateAlias("subclass1.subclass3", "s3")
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
.Add(Projections.Property("s2.NAME"))
.Add(Projections.Property("s3.CODE")))
.List();
```

You can go as deep as your need into your mapped classes to make an alias.